# Applying border-spacing to tbody elements only

Tags: css

I've applied:

```
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0em 2em;
```

to my table.  This provides spacing between each of the data rows, which is what I want, but it also adds spacing between the header row and the first data row.  How can I remove this spacing between the header row and the data rows?

Here's an example: https://jsbin.com/niwitaciti/edit?html,css,output

Comment: can you put whole code here?

Comment: you should add more code to put everything in context

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

using the [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) you can add sth like that

```
tr:first-child {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work: `border-spacing` is a property that applies to tables, not constituent rows.